# Windows 7 Safe Mode in minimal option keep on looping

Tags: windows

I have run msconfig and select safe mode in minimal option. After restarting, it keeps on loading repeatedly. I have tried to select Last Known Configuration but it returns back on loading. I could not log on and disable the safe mode in minimal. There is one option, to repair it . If I choose to repair Windows, will it go back to normal mode?Are all files still intact even if I proceed to repair it? I never had tried this option. Please help me. Are there any options other than repairing Windows to go back in normal mode?

thank you.

Comment: This is off topic for SO.  You might get help at SuperUser, although you may need to provide a bit more detail there to get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your facing a thing called [infinite loop](https://neosmart.net/wiki/startup-repair-infinite-loop/). This is probably caused because your [bootmanager](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsb/g/bootmgr.htm) file is corrupted. You can try fixing it by using the link that opens when you click bootmanager in the previous sentence (requires some knowledge of Windows).

If you want to learn more about the bootmanager (and how it works) click [here](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/windows-boot-manager-phase.html). Although you should only read it when you are interested in fixing it manually (requires some knowledge of Windows).

To answer your original question, whenever you select an option from the start-up repair screen that will remove some of your **personal** files **it will tell you before deleting anything**.

I've also faced this problem (it wasn't really the same as yours, but there are multiple issues that are called infinite loop as they are caused by the same error). I've ended up re-installing Windows. The good thing of Windows 7 is that whenever you re-install Windows it will ask you if you want to keep your old files, if you decide to keep the old files the installer will automatically add a folder to you main drive (usually C) named `Windows.old` which will contain your old data. Note that documents, your desktop and pictures etc. are saved, your Program Files directory will be copied to, but you will probably need to re-install all your programs. But in the end, you will keep your documents.

Comment: Hi sir! Thank you for giving time to response my question. I have asked Sir if old files from Windows could be retained because I have database saved in Windows. That's my main concern. It's okay if I re-install everything as long as that database is keep intact. I will try what you have suggested. I really appreciate your response and time.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark it as answer for so that others with the same problem can read it too. Good luck!

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for reminding me that sir. Have a nice day!:)

Comment: There are multiple repair options, I couldn't find which one your wanted to use. But IF something gets deleted, Windows will tell that your personal files will be destroyed and then you can either choose 'Yes' or 'No'. So you will have to click No. When using Start-up repair you files won't be touched. Good luck!

Comment: Haaah!!! Good luck to myself. I hope it will be fixed :)